# adding USB support to a Designjet 5500ps 42" using J4135A jetdirect card

Tags: windows-7, printing, printer

I have a designjet 5500 ps. It is 42in wide. I usually print through the parallels port, but always wanted to print through USB.

Recently my computer started not printing through the parallel port (parallel to USB staples cable). The printer only works using parallel cable on my friend's computer.

I bought a J4135A jetdirect card, put it into the computer, and now it shows up in my control panel. What steps do I need to take next to print with it? I tried printing to it using photoshop, but the card does not show up under the list of printers under photoshop when you go to print with it.

[image: designjet 5500ps J4135A jetdirect card]

My installer for the drivers fails, so does adding the printer manually using control panel on USB virtual port.

[image: designjet 5500ps driver error]

How should this card work out of the box? Do you just put it in the printer and connect to the computer (I'm using windows 7) and it should show up as a printer instead of the card itself?

Comment: hmm, I wonder what happens when you run the driver in compatibility mode? Any parallel port printer is likely old.

Comment: tried that with the same outcome. That helped install the drive through the installer on my friend's computer though. These printers are old indeed. There's a lot of them and they are great machines though, and are the only thing affordable enough for large-format and high-quality prints since they are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now, on a clean system install, i first install the drivers using the automatic installer called

> (HP Designjet 5500 Printer Series Light Installer (HPGL2) Release)
>   http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=82223&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4063

and say that I want to connect the printer later. Something on the LTPE port. Then I add the printer using the control panel and browse to the manual drivers. Manual drivers are the folder which is extracted when you download and unzip:

> HP Designjet 5500 Series HP-GL/2 Driver

I can confirm that it works for me on windows7 64 bit.